# How did Einstein know the transformation of an event in two frames is a Lorentz transformation?

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

I watched this lecture on Lorentz transformation (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhXWiAJBmzc). I'd say the tutor employed a simplistic and elegent approach to derive the transformation. But I also got these questions: How did Einstein know the transformation of an event in two frames was a Lorentz transformation which already prescribed time dilation and length contraction? How did he know it would not involve higher order relationships or other non-linear relationship? Another question: is it possible to derive length contraction and time dilation using a single reference frame and classical kinetics? Hope someone could enlighten me on this rudimentary questions.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#History Many physicists—including Woldemar Voigt, George FitzGerald, Joseph Larmor, and Hendrik Lorentz himself—had been discussing the physics implied by these equations since 1887.

Comment: http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Einstein_1905_relativity.pdf

Comment: Have you read Einstein’s original 1905 paper on the subject?

Comment: See "Chasing the Light  Einstein's Most Famous Thought Experiment" by John D.Norton. "https://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/papers/Chasing.pdf"

Comment: He may not have "known", he figured it out based on a couple simple principles and  lot of algebra.  Also, Lorentz had figured out these transforms before Einstein.

Comment: I generally don't recommend Wikipedia for physics, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations is (or at least was) a good read. That the world behaves the way Einstein predicted is a direct algebraic consequence of the fact that all physics is relative (and that space is geometric). The really curious thing is that Galileo knew these two facts, already. If he had had the proper algebraic tools at his command, he could have derived special relativity on a few pages some three hundred years before Einstein... but I doubt anybody would have believed him.

Comment: Oops... I didn't see that somebody made the same recommendation in an answer already. Apologies.

Comment: The English version of Einstein's 1905 paper is here: https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol2-trans/154   ON THE ELECTRODYNAMICS OF MOVING BODIES by A. Einstein [Annalen der Physik 17 (1905): 891-921]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your comments. 
Special relativity is a theory with assumptions and verified by result of experiments.

I found the following derivatation uses least assumption and is easiest to understand:

Since space is assumed to be homogeneous, the transformation must be linear. The most general linear relationship is obtained with four constant coefficients, A, B, γ, and b:

$$x'=\gamma x + b t \;$$
$$t'=A x + B t. \,$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations

Comment: You may also want to have a look at this wonderful website where Einstein's original papers are collected: https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/ . see e.g. https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol2-trans/154

Answer (score 0):

One can find two different approaches from Einstein, the first in his book,  "Zur Elektrodynamik Bewegter Körper von Albert Einstein, 1905", and the second in " Ueber the spezielle und allgemeine Relativitaetstheorie" . In the first he starts with the definition of time for a point at a constant distance from the origin of the moving system, "t1=0.5(t0+t2)". If you read this approach, you'd find it mathematically correct up to the point on page 13, where he multiplies the result by "a= ((c^2-v^2)^0.5)/c " . It is not clear,  why can't "a" have any other value. The second approach is mathematically wrong.
the most simple approach I found myself is to solve 2 equations x'=Ax+Bt   (!)    t'=ct+Dx (2) by applying the conditions for relative velocity and equal appearance of equal long stabs.  THIS results in  x'=Ax -Avt  (1)      t'=At-(A-1/A)x/v  (2) if we put x=ct and x'=ct', you get A=gamma and you'd have LT. By A=1 one gets  the Galileo transform